# React Native - don't update my code in the virtual device

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to build my own mobile app with react native, to support both platforms, this framework it's awesome, and I recently y created a project with these features:

**react-native-cli: 2.0.1**

**react-native: 0.51.0**

The problem is that when I modify my code from VS code
the changes are not reflected in the virtual device.

Here are my screenshots:

[My virtual device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSFIF.png)

[My code (App.js)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RIQ7.png)

I tried:

- stop and start the virtual device, re-start the project
- execute react-native start --reset-cache from the terminal

and nothing works.

Can anyone help me? I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: aggregate: If I press R,R (twice), the virtual device returns me this error "Could not connect to development server" (but is running)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to open dev menu in your app and press Enable live reloading and Enable hot reloading
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sergei!, I will prove your answer

Comment: Yeah, try also Enable hot reloading, works like a charm for me

Comment: I will try your option!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the react-native!
Do you know live reloading or hot reloading?
if you use mac, press command+shift+Z and click "enable live reloading" on your virtual device

Comment: Thanks man!, it didn't work, I click "enable live reloading" and execute "react-native run-android" and the device steal show me the default code